# Marionette document.querySelector('#test') returns null but doing this.$('#test') does not

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, handlebars.js, marionette

I have a simple marionette ItemView,

```
import Marionette from 'backbone.marionette';
import Tabs from '@component/tabs/src/js/views/Tabs';
import template from '../../../templates/partials/one/tabs.hbs'
export default Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template,

  onRender() {
    console.log(document.querySelector('#tabs-main')); //--> null
    console.log(this.$('#tabs-main')[0]); // gets appropriate dom element
  }
})
```

Is there a reason why document.querySelector returns null compared to doing this.$, i need to do document.querySelector because the library that I am using uses it internally when i pass in the id/class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to https://marionettejs.com/docs/v3.5.1/viewlifecycle.html#view-creation-lifecycle

In onRender, the template will be rendered in memory (i.e. this.$el), but not yet attached to the DOM.

You can use onAttached if the view's HTML needs to be in the DOM.

Note that DOM lookups are slower than lookups done against the view's el, so unless a lookup needs to occur against the DOM, is generally better to use onRender with this.$() lookups.

Edit: since you're using ItemView, must be using < v3, here is v2 doc for onAttach:
https://marionettejs.com/docs/v2.4.7/marionette.view.html#view-attach--onattach-event

2nd edit: adding snippet (sorry, took a while to find older marionette dependencies)

```js
var MyView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template: Handlebars.compile('<p id="hello-world">Hello World</p>'),
  onRender: function() {
    console.log('onRender');
    console.log('querySelector', document.querySelector('#hello-world'));
    console.log('querySelector equal null?', document.querySelector('#hello-world') === null);
    console.log('this.$el', this.$('#hello-world')[0]);
  },
  onAttach: function() {
    console.log('onAttach');
    console.log('querySelector', document.querySelector('#hello-world'));
    console.log('querySelector equal null?', document.querySelector('#hello-world') === null);
    console.log('this.$el', this.$('#hello-world')[0]);
  }
});

// ParentView to mock an application
var ParentView = Backbone.Marionette.LayoutView.extend({
    el: '.test-container',
    template: Handlebars.compile('<div class="my-region"></div>'),
    regions: {
      myRegion: '.my-region'
    },
    onRender: function() {
      var myView = new MyView();
      this.showChildView('myRegion', myView);
    }
});

var parentView = new ParentView();
parentView.render();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.3.1/handlebars.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.marionette/2.4.7/backbone.marionette.js"></script>

<div class="test-container"></div>
```

Comment: but when i console log the document, and i drill down i can clearly see the html element present

Comment: Added snippet illustrating my understanding of the situation and the subsequent behavior.

Comment: man thank you, didnt even know about that lifecycle method. helped me prevent a re-render

Comment: one more question, so my earlier comment about console.log(document) showing the element that im looking for, even know its there is it not safe to say it is attached?

Comment: FWIW, later marionette versions have simplified the lifecycle a bit. Honestly not sure about why it would show when drilling down if not attached (if looking at the document while at a breakpoint in onRender). I know that chrome console will update to the latest content for elements (as if it's logging the reference). For example, consoling out document in onRender, then letting the page load, the document element will show the current DOM, not the DOM at the point of the console log